# How to get local host name in C# on a Windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, windows, hostname, uwp

```
string machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
```

This code doesn't work for me, error code 'Environment' does not contain a definition for 'MachineName'

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Universal App with C#

Please also list the namespace I need to use when you post an answer.

Comment: just guessing - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.gethostnames.aspx ?

Comment: Dosen't seem to work. Can't find that function even I use the Windows.Networking.Connectivity namespace

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use [`NetworkInformation.GetHostNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.gethostnames.aspx).

```
var hostNames = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
```

But note that this method will return multiple `HostName`s.

In my case, it returns four `HostName`s of which `DisplayName`s are  *MyComputerName*, *MyComputerName.local* plus two IP addresses.

So I guess it's probably safe to do -

```
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;


var hostNames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
var hostName = hostNames.FirstOrDefault(name => name.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)?.DisplayName ?? "???";
```

Comment: You have to include 'using System.Linq;' for this works fine, I guess.