# How do I get the computer domain name in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10

I already tried the folowing:

```
 IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();
 var current = users
      .Where( p =>
          p.AuthenticationStatus == UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated &&
          p.Type == UserType.LocalUser
      )
      .FirstOrDefault();

 string dominio = (string) await current.GetPropertyAsync( KnownUserProperties.DomainName ); // cause an error
```

Not worked: "A method was called at an unexpected time"

How do I get the domain name or domainname\username?

Comment: Which method call caused the exception? Where in your program are you making this call?

Comment: Sorry. Edited the question

Comment: If the program is running on the user's machine, then you can use `string dominio = Environment.UserDomainName;`

Comment: Enviroment.UserDomainName not work because it is  a Windows 10 machine and I'm trying to do a  UWP app

Comment: Are you using windows 10 professional

Comment: I'm using a VM running Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview

Comment: If a user is "Locally Authenticated", do they belong to a domain? And this questions sounds a lot like [Unable to get some user account information in UWP app...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952503/unable-to-get-some-user-account-information-in-uwp-app-in-premise-active-direc) question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread but did not helped. I'm still getting the "A method was called at an unexpected time"

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly worked.

```
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;


var hostNames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
var hostName = hostNames.FirstOrDefault(name => 
         name.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)?
         .DisplayName ?? "???";
```

From: [How to get local host name in C# on a Windows 10 universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876966/how-to-get-local-host-name-in-c-sharp-on-a-windows-10-universal-app)