# Environment.MachineName equivalent for .NET Standard 1.4

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, computer-name

I am creating a class library that will be used in a WPF project and a .NET Core project. I am trying to get the name of the machine using my application.

In both .NET Core and the WPF application I can use `Environment.MachineName` value. However in my .NET Standard Class library I cannot.

I get the following error:

> 'Environment' does not contain a definition for 'MachineName'

I tried doing what the answer suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876966/how-to-get-local-host-name-in-c-sharp-on-a-windows-10-universal-app) but when I try to add `System.Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()` I get the following error:

> The name 'Windows' does not exist in the current context

I assume that this only works for Windows 10 Universal Apps? Either way I would prefer a platform independent way of getting the machine name (this way seems like its meant for windows machines only)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Environment.MachineName` is only available in .NET Standard > 1.5 using the `System.Runtime.Extensions` NuGet package (in .NET Standard 2.0 it is available automatically).

As an alternative, you can either use `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` by referencing the `System.Net.NameResolution` NuGet package or resolve the `COMPUTERNAME` (win) or `HOSTNAME` (*nix) environment variables via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @martin-ullrich. I ended up with `var name = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUMPUTERNAME") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOSTNAME");`

Comment: @Anders I copied this code and haven't realized you have a typo in "CUMPUTERNAME" :)